# preventDefault on submitting form

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I would like run function on my form submit (validate with Foundation framework) :

```
$($newsletter).on('formvalid.zf.abide', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert('validate!');
    openRevealNewsletter(this.getAttribute('action'));
});
```

I've my alert when my form is valid, but my preventDefault() don't work. My form is submitted :(

Comment: Try using "return false;"

Comment: to prevent a form from **submit**, you'd need to preventDefault on the **submit** event - perhaps

Comment: ev.stopPropagation(); 
rerurn false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercept submit with `submit` event.

```
$($newsletter).on("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit intercepted");
  return false;
});
$($newsletter).on("forminvalid.zf.abide", function(e,target) {
  console.log("form is invalid");
  //show error messages
});
$($newsletter).on("formvalid.zf.abide", function(e,target) {
  console.log("form is valid");   
  //process form
  openRevealNewsletter(this.getAttribute('action'));
});
```

Comment: that would always prevent submit happening ... what if the form is valid :p

Comment: I suppose OP wants to prevent default and do something with javascript instead. `openRevealNewsletter(this.getAttribute('action'));`

Comment: Default action is prevented in all cases. If form is **invalid**, show errors. If form is **valid** submit it with AJAX or do whatever processing OP wants. Processing happens only if form is valid. Disabling default behaviour is unrelated I guess, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

first of all easy way to make this work done is use

```
 <button type="button">submit</button>
```

instead of

```
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
```

to submit the form programmatically in java script use

```
     document.getElementById("FormID").submit();
```

this will submit your form when you call this script also prevent default will not required once you replace submit with button in submit button

Comment: Far too simple, nowhere near enough jQuery…

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$($newsletter).on('formvalid.zf.abide', function(ev) {
   alert('validate!');
   openRevealNewsletter(this.getAttribute('action'));
   return false;
});
```

This will stop the form post on a false returned value.

When you are using `return false`,automatically it is doing 3 separate things when you call it:

`1.event.preventDefault();`

`2.event.stopPropagation();`

`3.Stops callback execution and it returns immediately when callback are called.`